# Trying to Edit a Foreign Key Field to one model in the other model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models TextDocument and TranslatedText as shown below. I upload a pdf to another model (Document), and if it has text, perform some OCR and save the OCR text in the original_text field in TextDocument. If the text is not in English, I then translate it and store the translation in the translated_text field in TranslatedText. TranslatedText has a foreign key relationship to TextDocument.

```
class TextDocument(models.Model):
    document_id = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    original_text_file_name = models.FileField('OCR File name', upload_to=settings.DOCUMENT_FOLDER_OCR, default=settings.DEFAULT_OCR_PATH, storage=OverwriteStorage())
    original_text = models.TextField(default=get_default_text, blank=True)
    original_language = models.CharField(default=get_default_language, max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name="date created")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, verbose_name="last update")

class TranslatedText(models.Model):
    document_id = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    text_document_id = models.ForeignKey(TextDocument, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    translated_text_file_name = models.FileField('Translated File name', upload_to=settings.DOCUMENT_FOLDER_TRANSLATION, default=settings.DEFAULT_TRANSLATION_PATH, storage=OverwriteStorage())
    translated_text = models.TextField()
    translated_language = models.CharField(default=get_default_language, max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name="date created")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, verbose_name="last update")
```

In the TransaltedTextAdmin change page I display the translated_text field in a TextBox so it can be edited if needed. I also want to display the TextDocument field orignal_text as an editable field so if the OCR messed up, the admin can change that, too. However, I only seem to be able to display the original_text field as a read_only field, and cannot edit it.

```
class TranslatedTextAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    logger.debug("TranslatedTextDocumentAdmin START")
    list_display = ('get_document', 'get_document_id', 'get_document_state', 'translated_text_file_name', 'translated_language', 'updated', 'created', 'get_thumb',)
    #readonly_fields = ('get_original_document','updated', 'created','translated_language', 'translated_text_file_name', 'original_text',)
    readonly_fields = ('get_original_document','updated', 'created','translated_language', 'translated_text_file_name', )
    form = TranslatedTextAdminForm

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('translated_text', 'original_text', 'get_original_document', 'translated_text_file_name', 'translated_language', 'updated', 'created'),
            #'fields': ('translated_text', 'text_document_id__original_text', 'get_original_document', 'translated_text_file_name', 'translated_language', 'updated', 'created'),
            'classes': ('extrapretty',),
        }),
    )

  def get_translated_text(self, obj):
        return TranslatedText.objects.get_translation_metadata_text(obj.document_id) 

class TranslatedTextAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    original_text = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TranslatedTextAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['original_text'] = forms.CharField(widget=AdminTextareaWidget(attrs={'cols': 40, 'rows': 10}), required=False)
        self.fields['original_text'].initial = TextDocument.objects.get_text_metadata_text(self.instance.document_id)           

    class Meta:
        model = TranslatedText
        fields = '__all__'
```

I have tried using a TranslatedTextAdminForm as shown, but I can only get the original_text field to display an a Textarea that cannot be edited. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was having a Outer Limits moment. It seems my code was working. I had to clear the browser cache to see the changes. 
We now return you to our originally scheduled prgram.